# How can I access to [id]/routeName in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I have simple project that when user go to the link like: **localhost:3000/course/[id]**
Then user click join and the url will change to **localhost:3000/course/[id]/routeName**
How can i create folder like that in pages ?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want what Next calls 'Multiple dynamic route segments'. Inside of your `/pages` directory:

- you want a folder called `course`
- inside of that you'd have another folder called `[id]`
- inside of that folder, you'd want a file called `[routeName].js`

The path would look like:

```
/pages/course/[id]/[routeName].js
```

Comment: yes, it worked! Thank you so much, i very want to upvote your answer but i can't because i don't have enough reputations. Sorry so much! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out !
If you have the same problem like me !

```
pages
   |-categories
       |-[category_slug]
           |-index.js     
           |-product
               |-[product_slug].js
```

That's it!